# How to Add "Z" at the end of date string with moment in javascript and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

I want to format my date such that the "Z" letter appears at the end of the date.

I've tried many things but nothing seems to be working. i need it to be in the format of "YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z" right now it is in this format except for the Z

How can I include the Z at the end using moment, note that i need the date at the start of the day, as in everything after the "T" is 0.

My Code:

```
   console.log(moment(req.body.to, "YYYY-MM-DD").startOf('day'))

   'from': {$eq:  moment(req.body.from, "YYYY-MM-DD").startOf('day')},
```

output of the log:

```
(moment("2022-10-09T00:00:00.000"))
```

Comment: `moment("2022-10-09T00:00:00.000\Z")`?

Comment: @Justinas that is the output not the code

Comment: While not directly related to the core of the question, you should consider that `moment` has been [EOL](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for over 2 years now - if you need support for specific operations beyond what's provided in bare-bones JavaScript you may consider switching to a comparable library like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/)

Comment: @esqew thank you for the suggestion, but do you have any solution using javascript/moment?

Comment: If your date is already in "YYYY-MM-DD" format, why not `req.body.to + 'T00:00:00.000Z'` because that's exactly what you're trying to do with moment.js, except it's parsed to a date and moment object in between (for no practical effect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking from the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) you could do:

```js
moment(req.body.to, "YYYY-MM-DD").startOfDay().format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]")
```

> Escaping characters
> To escape characters in format strings, you can wrap the characters in square brackets.

Or, since you only want zeroes:

```js
moment(req.body.to, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("YYYY-MM-DD[T00:00:00.000Z]")
```

Or, since your example indicates that your date is already in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, why not just do:

```js
`${req.body.to}T00:00:00.000Z`
```